# Google Calendar Gadget needs to know which event is currently being looked at

Tags: google-calendar-api, gdata-api, google-gadget

I am programming my first [google calendar sidebar gadget](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/gadgets/) right now. When the user is in Google Calendar, I plan to have them open up an event, and when they are in view/edit page, it will use that event's data to find other similar events.

The problem is, I can't figure out a way to know which event is currently being looked at. Once I can tell that, I don't think I'll have much trouble doing the rest.

So, I am wondering:

1. Does the Google Calendar API provide views information for sidebar gadgets? I think the answer is no but I'd like to be wrong.
2. Is there any other way I might get this information, like say by looking up info from the page's DOM?

Thanks in advance! I might post this question elsewhere, but I will be sure to post the answer here regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's subscribeToEvents that I need. It was right under my nose in the API docs...